# Manually installed applications are not found in Installed Applications list after changing system language

Tags: software-installation, language-support

I'm a new Linux user.

I've installed Intellij Idea and Webstorm. Everything was fine. But then I changed the system language from Bangla to English(US) (I am from Bangladesh, but I prefer to see the dates in English). And since then I cannot find Intellij Idea and WebStorm in installed apps.

So I changed back to Bangla but it didn't fix the problem. If I go to the directory where I extracted the files and run the command `./idea.sh` then the program runs alright, I can code there and run it. But again when I close Intellij idea then I cannot find it in the Installed application section. I also tried Software Center. But there it shows as not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't created two things:

1. A terminal launcher, and
2. An entry for the `.desktop` file.

Launch the apps like you did from their folders then in the menu go to the **Tools** menu and under it select **Create Command-line launcher** and **Create Desktop Entry** respectively. Now you should see the icons to launch the apps.

[image: options dialog]